# Autocomplete and text search memory issues in apostrophe-cms: need ideas

Tags: mongodb, apostrophe-cms

I’m having trouble to use the text search and the autocomplete because I have a piece with +87k documents, some of them being big (~3.4MB of text).

### I already:

1. Removed every field from the text index, except `title` , `searchBoost` and `seoDescription` ; these are the only fields copied to `highSearchText` and the field `lowSearchText` is always set to an empty string.
2. Modified the standard text index, including the fields `type`, `published` and `trash` in the beginning of it. I'm also modified the queries to have equality conditions on these fields. The result returned by the command db.aposDocs.stats() shows:
   `type_1_published_1_trash_1_highSearchText_text_lowSearchText_text_title_text_searchBoost_text: 12201984 (~11 MB, fits nicely in memory)`
3. Verified that this index is being used, both in ‘toDistinc’ query as well in the final ‘toArray’ query.

### What I think is the biggest problem

The documents have many repeated words in the title, so if the user types a word present in 5k document titles, the server suffers.

### Idea I'm testing

The MongoDB docs says that to improve performance the entire collection must fit in RAM (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#storage-requirements-and-performance-costs, last bullet).

So, I created a separate collection named “search” with just the fields highSearchText (string, indexed as text) and highSearchWords (array, also indexed), which result in total size of ~ 19 MB.

By doing the same operations of the standard apostrophe autocomplete in this collection, I achieved much faster, but similar results.

I had to write events to automatically update the search collection when the piece changes, but it seems to work until now.

### Issues

I'm testing this search collection with the autocomplete. For the simple text search, I’m just limiting the sorted response to 50 results. Maybe I'll have to use the search collection as well, because the search could still breaks.

Is there some easier approach I'm missing? Please, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what is happening when you try to make queries before your changes, and exactly what kind of queries.

Comment: When I make search or autocomplete queries, the server takes too long to respond, the mongo connection ends and sometimes the mongo container dies. I think this happens because the mongo sort operation with text searches consumes too much resources when run on large collections with big documents. This is not an apostrophe problem. I could solve it by adding more memory (the collection have ~800MB), but it's too expensive.  The separate collection is workig good with autocomplete, but I'll also have to adapt to ordered text search. Clear enough?

Comment: Interesting. I don't think this is a question with one clear answer, but I can note that we created the apostrophe-elasticsearch module for an enterprise client who has possibly similar issues with text search at scale. So far they are still using mongodb's text search, but I don't think that was due to any failure of the elasticsearch module.

Comment: I thought about use elastic search too, but it will possibly consume more resources. I discover too late that, with mongodb, everything must fit in memory to be fast. If I had separated meta information as a piece and the significant data in a different collection, maybe I would be fine. The text index don't help if the rest of the collection is big, even if the index is small. So, a collection dedicated only to the search fields seems to work very well. I'll try to write some code do create a big colleciton to reproduce this issue and make some tests. Thanks.

Comment: @TomBoutell Here it is: https://github.com/souzabrs/misc/tree/master/big-pieces. Note the difference between the times. More than one second is very bad for autocomplete and the smallest of default autocomplete results is the last one (~1863 ms). Using pretty much the same process, but with a separate collection, the times were reduced by a factor of 100.

Comment: Text indexes do help. Have you used the mongodb shell's "explain" feature to get more information about whether the index is really being used by the query? You can view the queries being made by starting the site this way:

APOS_LOG_ALL_QUERIES=1 node app

Comment: Yes, they do help and I think the text index is being used with the apostrophe native autocomplete. But I don't know why i'ts fastest with a separate collection. I think the sort operation is the problem. Even using the index, mongo needs to calculate the textScore for all matching documents, and apparently to do this the collection must fit in memory ([see this, last bullet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#storage-requirements-and-performance-costs)). Note: the code I shared to generate random documents were inserting non-published pieces, so, I fixed it.

Comment: @TomBoutell After many tests, [here](https://github.com/souzabrs/misc/blob/master/big-pieces/conclusions.md) are my conclusions. If you need more explanation, I'm available. In the end I made a humble suggestion that I could start drafting, if you think it would be interesting.