# Mongodb performance increase likes field or return size of array

Tags: mongodb

My question is: If i have for example an collection called `posts`. A user can like a post but only once so i need to save him somewhere, maybe in an embedded array called `userThatLiked` so that he cant like twice. Is it better to have a field `likes` and to increase that value if a new user likes it, or is it better to return the length of the embedded array `userThatLiked`? Does this matter in performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you canhave embedded documents like

```
{
    _id: post_1
    likes : [ user_id_1,user_id_2,user_id_3]
}
```

When a user click like button, you should use `addtoSet` instead of `push`

Comment: my question is if for example 10 million ppl like that post, my `likes` array will be huge. is it better to have a field `likes` that is being increased or doesnt it matter if i just return the size of the array?

Comment: it doesnt matter if you save in the array like what I posted. But if u put nested documents for each and every user, if will be a problem.

Comment: no my idea was just to save the `_id` of the user that likes

Comment: then it doesn't matter from my exp

Comment: @Ifaruki MongoDB has a document size limit of 16MB https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit . So if you really think that you will have millions of array elements, that will actually be a problem.

Comment: @TheeSritabtim thank you. my problem here is i dont have a reference so i dont know how much 16mb are. are there any examples?

Comment: You can run [db.collection.stats()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/) to see your average object size and other stats for you collection.


Another reference: an ObjectId is 12 bytes, so 1 million likes will cost you 12MB
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/


More discussion about document size vs performance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837906/mongodb-does-document-size-affect-query-performance